# Is it possible to use a if statement and echo or print iframe?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, iframe, echo

So what I would like to do is there is a variable if the variable = 4 it shows the embedded map, is it possible ? Like use echo or print ?

```
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3690.394035580924!2d114.14653071466621!3d22.33874584714393!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3404007b6cca3859%3A0xf78318a768321055!2sFlow%20Bookshop!5e0!3m2!1sen!2shk!4v1620637580481!5m2!1sen!2shk" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Comment: You'll need an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this HTML is within a .php file, then just use an `if` statement:

```
<?php if ($x == 4) { ?> 
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3690.394035580924!2d114.14653071466621!3d22.33874584714393!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3404007b6cca3859%3A0xf78318a768321055!2sFlow%20Bookshop!5e0!3m2!1sen!2shk!4v1620637580481!5m2!1sen!2shk" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
<?php } ?>
```